# Android image position

Tags: android, image, layout, position

I have a problem. With this image I can explain better.

[image]

To do this i use this .xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img_black" />            

</RelativeLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

I would like to put the black rectangle at the bottom, so as to eliminate the red line under the black rectangle, and that remains, however, over the green one. Obviously the black rectangle is an image, while the rest are just background colors, it was just to make it clear that I would put the image (the black rectangle) as low as possible, half the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ImageView try to use `android:background="@drawable/img_black"` instead of `android:src` like as below:

```
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/img_black" 
        android:layout_marginTop = "20dp"/>
```

Comment: In this way i don't have what i want. Because i set the black image how background, but i want only put at the bottom. Because if i set the black image how background the program resize my image, and i don't want it.

Comment: @user3043062 didn't get you bro... Is it that you want red upper part but not the red bottom part ? is it what u r saying ?

Comment: Yess! I want only move the image.

Comment: Use as i said but give the top margin. Answer edited: